# Explicitly known graph families where the product of the size of biggest independent set and biggest clique is "small"

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Are there explicit constructions of graph families with the following property:

$G_n$ is the graph on $n$ vertices in the family, $\omega(G_n)$ is the size of the biggest clique in the graph $G_n$, $\alpha(G_n)$ is the size of the biggest independent set in $G_n$, then we have

$$\omega(G_n)\alpha(G_n) \leq tn$$

for some $t$ where $t<0.8$.

Observe that,

$t=1$ can be trivially achieved by taking the family with $K_n$ (complete graph on $n$ vertices).

$t=0.8$ can be achieved by taking the family where $G_{5i}$ is the graph with $i$ copies of $C_5$.

Comment: paley graph ${}{}{}$

Comment: I guess either $\alpha(G)$ or $\omega(G)$ (but not both) is to be the size of
the biggest *coclique*, not clique as written.
$$ $$
In general, for any explicit graph $G$ on $n$ vertices that attains
$\alpha \omega = tn$ we can use the graphs $k\cdot G$ to attain
the same value of $t$.  For example, the Paley graph with $n=17$ has
$\alpha = \omega = 3$, giving $t = 9/17 < 0.53$.
[NB the pentagon $C_5$ is also a Paley graph.]
Wikipedia's entry on Ramsey's theorem reports that $R(10,10) \geq 798$; 
if that's from an explicit construction then we get $t = 81/797 < 0.102$.

Comment: Unless you really care about very small $n$, I believe what you're looking for are explicit constructions of near-Ramsey graphs. In the computer science literature, this is done via constructions of "two-source extractors"; the state of the art are graphs of size $N=2^n$ for $n$ large enough that contain no clique or independent set of size more than $\log(N)^{o(\log\log\log N)}$.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle this is a bit old, but you may be interested to know that there are now apparently explicit constructions of graphs with no clique or independent set of size more than $\log^{C}(n)$ for an absolute constant $C\geq 1$ thanks to a very recent breakthrough of Li: https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2023/023/. This is optimal up to the value of $C$ by classical bounds.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $\alpha$ and $\omega$ must be at least $2$.
There are known explicit families of graphs $G$ for which $\omega = 2$
(so $G$ is triangle-free) and $\alpha \ll n^\theta$ for some $\theta < 1$,
so $t \ll n^{\theta-1} \to 0$.  Erdos (1966) attained this with
$\theta = (3/2) \log_2 (3/2) < 0.88$; according to
[https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~erdosproblems/erdos/newproblems/R4n.html](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eerdosproblems/erdos/newproblems/R4n.html)
the current record is $2/3 < 0.67$, by Alon (1994), whose paper
[https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/r3k1.pdf](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/r3k1.pdf)
also cites the 1966 paper by Erdos and a few later improvements.
Alon constructs his graphs on pages 2-3, proves the triangle-free property
in a paragraph on page 3, and gives the upper bound on $\omega$ in
two further pages (proof of Theorem 2.1).

The optimal bound on $\theta$ is $1/2 + o(1)$,
but this has yet to be attained by explicit graphs.
In the comments **Jason Gaitonde** reports that there are
explicit "two-source extractors" that yield large graphs with
$t \ll n^{\epsilon-1}$ for all $\epsilon > 0$,
but with both $\alpha \to \infty$ and $\omega \to \infty$;
I think that this must be much more recent work.

**References**

N. Alon: Explicit Ramsey graphs and orthonormal labelings,
*Electronic J. Combinatorics* **1** (1994), R12.

P. Erdos: On the construction of certain graphs,
*J. Combinatorial Theory* **17** (1966), 149--153.

Comment: Yes, this is much more recent (see e.g. Barak, et al, Ann. of Math. 2012). A $(n,k)$ 2-source disperser is a function $f:(\{0,1\}^n)^2\to \{0,1\}$ such that for any $A,B\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ of size $2^k$, $f$ is not constant on $A\times B$. $f$ encodes a bipartite graph on $2^{n+1}$ vertices with no complete or empty bipartite subgraph graph with $2^k$ vertices on each side. This can be converted to a nonbipartite graph on $2^n$ vertices with no clique or independent set of size $2^{k-1}$. The best explicit constructions I know [Li, CCC 2019] give $k=O(\log(n)\log\log(n)/\log\log\log(n))$.

Comment: @JasonGaitonde Thanks, that is what I was looking for